# Not picking up id of control in code behind

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, webforms

I have a basic webform(Default.aspx) that I created using and master page and bizarrely I am not able to access the id of a control in the code behind.

```
<ul id="topicsList" runat="server">
                                <asp:Label ID="labUserName" runat="server"/>
                            </ul>

IDomainObjectRepository rep;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    rep = new DomainObjectRepository();
    rep.GetDomainObjectsByType("Visuals Product Label");
    /*labUserName not picked up by intellisense*/

}
```

any pointers as to why this could be the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is likely due to your Code-front not being referenced by code behind, or vice versa. Make sure you have the following (double check the CodeBehind and code-behind class marry up):

```
public class _Default : Page
{
   // Your load event
}

<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
```